# Ext.NET-JSON Deserialize-model fields empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, extjs, ext.net

I use ext grid panel in my web page. I want to deserialize my model fields from gridpanel store. But it s not work. After deserialize, model created but fields empty.

My Model:

```
public class GenKullanici : BaseEntity
{
    public Int32? Kod { get; set; }
    public string KullaniciKod { get; set; }
    public string PersonelKod { get; set; }
    public string Adi { get; set; }
    public string Soyadi { get; set; }
    public string AktifEH { get; set; }
    public DateTime? KayitTarihi { get; set; }
    public string BelediyeKod { get; set; }
    public DBActionType ActionType { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public string BelediyeAck { get; set; }
}
```

My json data:

```
[{"Kod":"3","KullaniciKod":"DENEME","PersonelKod":null,"Adi":"DENEME ADI","Soyadi":"DENEME SOYAD","AktifEH":"H","KayitTarihi":"2014-07-21T17:43:35","BelediyeKod":"3313","BelediyeAck":"Tarsus Belediyesi","ID":"ext-32-2","ActionType":2,"FieldList":"Kod|AktifEH|PersonelKod|"}]
```

I try:

```
list = JSON.Deserialize<List<EntitySpace.User.GenKullanici>>(data);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: a guess `list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EntitySpace.User.GenKullanici>>(data);`

Comment: just go through http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/397574/Use-Csharp-to-get-JSON-Data-from-the-Web-and-Map-i

Comment: var myobjList = JSON.Deserialize<List<EntitySpace.User.GenKullanici>>(data)[0];

Comment: @unique_id  Thank u. I found my problem. My base class has [DataContract] attribute. When i remove [DataContract] attribute, it works.

Comment: @sakir Thank u for your comment and than u for edit tags and add ext.net tag.

Comment: @CocLn your welcome ,I hope it works for you